# Match text between two words with grep on multiple lines

Tags: grep

I know there's the a syntax you can use, like:

```
grep -oP '.word1.*?word2'
```

but this doesn't work on multiple lines. So here's an example input:

```
user1:x:1001:1001::/home/user1home:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home:/bin/bash
```

The command I tried to use was:

```
grep -oP '.1002:1002.*?user4home'
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a file z2 containing:

```
user1:x:1001:1001::/home/user1home:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home:/bin/bash first
user1:x:1001:1001::/home/user1home:/bin/bash
user2:x:1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home:/bin/bash second
```

The utility `cgrep` will produce:

```
$ cgrep -e '1002:1002' +w '/home/user4home' z2
========================================
user2:x:1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home:/bin/bash first
========================================
user2:x:1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home:/bin/bash second
```

More information on `cgrep` (*context, windowing grep*):

```
cgrep   shows context of matching patterns found in files (man)
Path    : ~/executable/cgrep
Version : 8.15
Type    : ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYS ...)
Home    : http://sourceforge.net/projects/cgrep/ (doc)
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
grep -Pzo "1002:1002.*(\n|.)*/home/user4home" file
```

It will match word starting with `1002:1002`, till `/home/user4home`.

Comment: Thanks, that's awesome, can you please explain what each part does? :D

Comment: @Farcas, read the man page to learn what -z does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pcregrep`:

```
$ pcregrep -Mo "(?s)1002:1002.*/home/user4home" file
1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home
```

The `(?s)` modifier (which may also be used in `grep -P`) makes `.` include `\n` so that there is no need to match newlines explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Or you convert the file to one line and convert it back.

```
$ cat file | tr \\n \\0 | grep -oa '1002:1002.*user4home' | tr \\0 \\n
1002:1002::/home/user2home:/bin/bash
user3:x:1003:1003::/home/user3home:/bin/bash
user4:x:1004:1004::/home/user4home
```

You need to add `-a` to `grep` to treat binary files as text.

Comment: nice!  But note the UUOC.  `< file tr \\n \\0 ...` works well.